# Laravel, faker: Call to undefinded function

Tags: laravel, faker

Call to undefined function sentence()

When calling sentence() from faker in laravel 5.8.

I'm guesing it's an import issue but I cannot figure it out.

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Activity::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'when' => $faker->name,
        'activity' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 5, $variableNbWords = true),
        'learned' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 2, $variableNbWords = true),
        'role' => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 2, $variableNbWords = true),
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now(),
        'user_id' => rand(1, 10),
    ];
});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I put $faker-sentence instead of $faker->sentence.

Comment: $faker->sentence is the correct syntax. Also, much easier if you create Factory using the artisan make command.